# How to throw FaultException from self hosting wcf service?

Tags: c#, wcf, fault, self-hosting

I'm planning to host the service in windows service, but I'm thinking about the problem described in the title. Anyone had similar issue?
Thanks

### Update

The problem is that when you throw an exception in WinForms/WPF/Win Service app, the program crashes and you'll have to restart it.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate what the problem actually is.

Comment: Are you trying to throw a new exception as an answer to some validation rule in your service, expecting the client to catch it and process it ?

Comment: did you try catch (FaultException) block ?

Comment: @Laurent yes that's what I'm trying to do. I could host the service in IIS but it would harden deployment. If it's possible to achieve what I want, I prefer Windows Service

Comment: The same question is asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369882/wcf-web-service-custom-exception-error-to-client - They talk about Web WCF Service, are you doing it the way this answer explain ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369882/wcf-web-service-custom-exception-error-to-client/1369956#1369956

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exception does not always crash your server. Even an unexpected server-side exception will be transferred to the client. It is considered more severe than an expected one though, faulting the channel.

The basic idea is to include the expected exceptions (faults) in you interface contracts . There are many ways to do that, here is [an introduction article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ankithakur/ExceptionHandlingWCF12282007072617AM/ExceptionHandlingWCF.aspx).

And of course you need decent exception handling at the server.

Comment: Hmm, that article mentions to catch an exception and throw a FaultException (which is not handled by try catch). Actually this is what I want to do but wouldn't this crash the service? I guess the only way is to catch FaultException after it is forwarded to the client. Do you know how do to that? thanks

Comment: Just try it. WCF will encode it and raise it again on the Client.

Answer (score 0):

A thing you can try is to intercept any exceptions by hooking to the ThreadException event in the Main method entry point **of your Host application** to check whether it is a FaultException.

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());

        // Hook to this event below
        Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
    }

    static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception is FaultException)
            return; // Bypass FaultExceptions;
        else
            throw e.Exception; // Throw otherwise
    }
}
```