# Error handling/reporting in Windows Phone 7.1 + Azure WebRole

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, azure, windows-phone-7.1

What would be the most mainstream way to report errors from a Azure Service to a Windows Phone 7 application via `basicHttpBinding`? Since Silverlight uses the Async pattern i can't use `try catch` and when a exception happens on the service side the client then throws a exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*have a look here:[Answer on StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369882/wcf-web-service-custom-exception-error-to-client)*

The quick and dirty approach is to do the following:

```xml
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EmployeeManager_Behavior">
       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
```

This will simply take the server-side error and provide its details to the client.

A nicer approach is to use the `IErrorHandler` interface. This allows WCF errors to be handled on the server and reported back to the client in a more controlled way.

You can find out more about this approach in the [MSDN Documentation for IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx).