# Throwing a FaultException<T> from a WCF services causes 'The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.'

Tags: c#, wcf, error-handling

When throwing a `FaultException<CustomFault>` like this:

```
throw new FaultException<CustomFault>(new CustomFault("Custom fault message"));
```

I get the following: "The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason."
Now according to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199.aspx) one isn't required to use the `FaultReason`

I have the following Service Contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(CustomFault))]
CustomType[] SomeMethod(int someParameter);

[DataContract]
public class CustomFault
{
    private string report;

    public CustomFault(string message)
    {
        this.report = message;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Message
    {
        get { return this.report; }
        set { this.report = value; }
    }
}
```

There is a comment on the MSDN article that suggest it is mandatory to use the other `FaultReason`, but in several other places I have seen people arguing that you shouldn't use the `FaultReason` unless necessary.

So my question is as follows; is it really mandatory to use the `FaultReason` and if not - how can i prevent the exception raised when trying to throw a `FaultException`?

**EDIT**

By running the sample project from [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942778.aspx) I get the excact same behavior. Maybe it's caused by an update in .NET an the documentation/samples not being updated.

Comment: Whenever I've thrown `FaultException<TDetail>`s across WCF, I've not set a `Reason`, and I've not had a problem. Can't shed any light on why it's not working for you, sorry.

Comment: Do you also get the exception when you invoke your service without the VS debugger attached?

Comment: No I don't. Maybe it's just a question of unhandled exception levels in the debugger. But it seems wrong to me that the documentation is using a fault handling strategy which causes an exception :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fault **reason is required** while the **details are optional**.

WCF uses the value of the [FaultException.Reason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultexception.reason.aspx) property to populate the `<faultstring>` element of the SOAP Fault, which is required by [the SOAP specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383507):

> **faultstring**
>   The faultstring element is intended to provide a human readable explanation of the fault and is not intended for algorithmic
>   processing. *[...]* It MUST be present in a SOAP Fault element and
>   SHOULD provide at least some information explaining the nature of the
>   fault.

Hence, you **must provide a reason** for the fault when throwing a [FaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576192.aspx) from a WCF service.

Comment: That makes sence. However, all the examples and documentation I find on the web seems to ignore this which makes me think that there might be another way to solve this in WCF?

Comment: A complete sample project: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942778.aspx
And the FaultException class documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199.aspx

Comment: It' seems it's just a matter of the break options choosen in the VS debugger.