# WCF Service behaves differently when installed

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wix

I have written a WCF service which acts as a data access layer for my client applications.
The service loads and calls api from a managed assembly which I have referenced in my service project. A windows service is hosting my WCF service. Also I have implemented a wix installer to install my service. the communication is going to be only WCF-WCF

Now the problem is when I run the service from Visual studio then all the api's are working as expected but when I install my service then, api's don't throw exception but doesn't return expected result. To solve this problem I tried following things

1)Tried basicHttpBinding, wsHttpBinding and netTcpBinding
2)Changed the service log on setting as admin

Can someone point out the problem here? I tried lot of things suggested in different sites but nothing was helpful till now. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f15a5edf-b3ff-43e6-be90-b943141a286e/throwing-exception-from-wcf-service-client-not-receiving-same-error-message?forum=wcf and more relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369882/wcf-web-service-custom-exception-error-to-client

Comment: When you say you don't get the same results - can you elaborate?

Comment: Actually one of my API searches for all the devices(some kind off) connected to the machine. This API gives right count when run from visual studio but returns 0 when run using installed service. Actual implementation of the API is in the managed assembly I refer to. This assembly in turn calls some unmanaged code as well. I just call the API from the managed assembly in my service implementation after loading the assembly

Comment: The communication is not throwing any exception. I Service trace viewer

Comment: Maybe you run the service as a less privileged user when you run it as a service?

Comment: When you run Visual Studio you are running under your logon privileges.  The Service has it' own logon.  Set the Service to run as your account or an account with the same authority.

Comment: This is what I tried->Component Services->right clicked the service->in properties, I changed the Log on information and gave my account information. But this didnt solve my problem

Comment: Any help is appreciated. Im stuck with this from past 1 week